# Bluetooth settings doesn't exist in win 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I got a logilink bluetooth 4 stick and wanted to connect to my phone with it. Only problem is, bluetooth seems very broken on my system.

I installed the BlueSoleil software provided by logilink which prompted me to restart. After that, a grey bluetooth icon appeared in notifications, i right click on it -> turn on bluetooth but nothing happens.

The only other thing I can select with right click on it is my bluetooth device which opens a menu asking me if I want to use a USB/UART/PCMCIA/BCSP device and more detailed settings for those modes. None of these do anything.

All google results suggest I find "Bluetooth settings" either from start menu or control panel but it doesn't exist. From screenshots, it seems like a similar window to "my bluetooth device" but with more stuff.

Another suggestion was to make sure my bluetooth service was running so i went into services.msc, the only buetooth related service was Bluetooth Support Service which was disabled. I set the startup to auto and started the service but nothing  changed. There was no Bluetooth Service or anything else mentioning bluetooth.

To me it seems I must be missing a windows update or something, wouldn't surprise me since I manually install only security and sometimes functionality related updates. Where can I get the bluetooth stuffs?

Win 7 Ultimate SP1

Comment: This is a dumb but probably fundamental question: Are you sure you have Bluetooth device?

Comment: Open task manager. Find BlueSoleil** application s(i do not remember exactly how it is called but there is something like BlueSoleilCS.exe). Make sure you closed all of them because there are may be few. Next open Service Manager and stop BlueSoleilCS service. Start the service again and run BlueSoleil application. This is very common issue with latest BlueSoleil software.